# How to use latex2rtf without root installation

Tags: macos, terminal, file-conversion, latex

This is a very basic question, as I am a newbie on Unix systems. I have installed [latex2rtf](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net) following the OS X specific instructions. As I do not have root rights (university computer), I installed Xcode to modify the Makefile:

```
#Base directory - adapt as needed
# Unix:
DESTDIR?=/Users/.../latex2rtf
```

Where ... is my home folder. Then I run the commands `make; make check; make install` (could not use `sudo`) and latex2rtf was installed to latex2rtf folder in my home directory. If I try to open latex2rtf file in bin folder, I get a new terminal window, where I can write anything without any kind of response. If I write latex2rtf in terminal I get a message: `-bash: latex2rtf: command not found`

So a simple question: how do I use latex2rtf on OS X in this case?

Comment: You need to put /Users/.../latex2rtf on your PATH - Althogh for this software I would ask the system administrator how to get latex on the computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Mark for the solution, which was pretty basic, indeed:

Open your `.bash_profile` file in Home directory (you can use terminal to open it, or tick "Show Hidden Items" in Finder on OS X 10.9.4). Add following to it:

`export PATH=$PATH:/Users/.../latex2rtf/bin`

Where the part after ":" specifies the location of `latex2rtf` file. In this case "..." is the home directory.

Save the file and exit. Run following in terminal:

`source $HOME/.bash_profile`

`latex2rtf` command should work now in terminal. The code is from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/).